# How to find the closed form of the summation below without changing the lower and upper bound of summation?

Tags: algorithms, closed-form, geometric-series

[image]The lower bound of summation is i=0 and the upper bound of summation is log(n) - 1 (log is base 2).

Comment: It would have been better if you written out the question,  rather than display from a text.

Comment: Warning!!  The robot nannies are after you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^mx^k=\frac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}$, so $f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^mkx^{k-1}=\frac{(m+1)x^m(x-1)-x^{m+1}+1}{(x-1)^2}$  For your question you want $A=2f'(2)$ where $m=log_2(n)-1$.  So $A=log_2(n)\times n-2n+2$.

This derivation is for $log_2(n)$ an integer or $n=2^j$ for some integer $j$.  Otherwise you need to use a greatest integer function for the sum limit.

Comment: This is close but not quite right.  For f'(x) the exponent of x is k - 1 but it should be k in my case.

Comment: Note that the definition of A has a multiple of $2$  That is the extra power you want.

Comment: I see what you did there now.  That's a nice trick I'll have to keep in mind. Thanks.  Could you show me how you got the final answer as well?  I tried to solve it myself but I got log(n) - n - 1.

Comment: Actually I got log(n) - n + 1. Sorry

Comment: Nvm I understand how you got it now. Thank you very much for your guidance

Comment: I made an error in the calculation.  It has been corrected.

Comment: Ok I understand how you got the new answer from the new formula. Thanks again!